# Active frame extraction from motion capture

Tags: feature-detection, feature-selection

I am new to this area - I have a background in a Gait and Posture.

I have a series of motion files of timestamped coordinates (containing X, Y, and Z in mm) with a number of joints (30).

What would be the simplest way to extract the following from the motion observations. 1) The number of active features (i.e. active joints). 2) average speed of motion.

Same file is the format of NxP. Where P is the number of joints and N is the number of frame observations.

What I am looking for is some pointers into possible areas to explore.

Regards,

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of possibilities you might like to explore - *both using completely **free**, (and open source), software*:

1. [Python](http://www.python.org/) + [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)/[SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/) can easily read in your
   coordinate values and calculate the data you require - it is also
   possible to plot in 3D using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/).
2. You could use your positional data to animate a stick figure in
   [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) *- some of the test blends would provide a good starting point for this*.